how to make glass show up in my sene

i cant figer it out to fix it i thog someone wouod help me

This question is similar to: Transparent Glass Material Eevee Blender version 4.2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You could at least show your material setup for the glass. Is there a glass dome supposed to be in the scene? To me it looks as if you have made the glass invisible by setting the alpha to 0, but this is not the right way to create a glass material.

In Eevee, since Blender 4.2 you first need to activate the Raytracing option in the Render panel:

Then select your glass object and in the Material panel > Settings > Surface > choose Render Method > Dithered, activate Raytrace Transmission and choose the Thickness:

